# HP Printer scrolls "printing" forever - but nothing happens

Tags: windows-xp, printer, hp-officejet

I got a used HP Officejet 7130 all-in-one printer.  I tried printing a text document, and it shows up in the queue (and says "printing"), and the printer display says "Printing" "Press Cancel to cancel job." - and it cyles that text forever, but nothing ever happens (after a couple of initial quiet noises.)  I tried to print a test page from the printer, and I get the same "printing" message.

I checked the hp website, and this problem is not on their list.  (They are expecting a queue problem, error message, etc.)

I did initially get a message that it needs new ink cartridges, but I pressed  to get past that.  It's supposed to try to print anyway.  I don't want to buy ink cartridges for a printer that is broken.

When I press  it cancels correctly.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: The O/S isn't relevant - the printer test page doesn't print (initiated "from printer").  However, it's Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score -1):

It can probably have many reasons why the printer can be stuck while displaying "Printing".

Maybe my experience is of help for some people.

My HP Officejet 4500 has some mechanical problem where it pulls in the paper too far. Then it does nothing more than showing "Printing" on its display and one can only cancel the printing.

The workaround which is easy but took me some time to come up with, is to withhold the paper and only some seconds after the printer tries to pull in paper, to feed it.